# Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'new document from template' in Word 2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

Where 'new document' has Ctrl+N to start a new document, is there a keyboard shortcut that will present me with the templates windows to select a template to create a new document with? A search for answers here and elsewhere online hasn't yielded anything useful yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to say you want the following File/New dialog to show up on pressing a keyboard shortcut?

[image: Word 2010's File/New dialog]

That's quite easy to do! Most people don't know that keyboard shortcuts can be customized in Office apps as per user preferences. For example, I didn't like how Word 2010 popped up the Navigation Pane (Pain?) when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, instead of the simple Find and Replace dialog that older versions did, so I simply remapped the shortcut to the older dialog and now all's fine with the wor(l)d! :)

1. Go to File / Options (indented under Help) / Customize Ribbon
2. Press the **Keyboard shortcuts: *Customize*** button shown below:

   [image: Word 2010's keyboard shortcut customization #1]
3. Select **All Commands** under Categories and **FileNew** under Commands
4. Navigate to/click in the **Press new shortcut key** field and press your desired shortcut (I have pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backquote/tilde key) in the screenshot below:

   [image: Word 2010's keyboard shortcut customization #2]
5. Click **Assign** (the shortcut key will move to the **Current keys** area)
6. Finally, click **Close** and **OK** in the Word Options dialog

   [image: Word 2010's keyboard shortcut customization #3]
7. You're done! Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and watch the magic unfold! :D

Note #1: If you go through the default mapped shortcuts, you'll see that it's very much possible to assign multiple keyboard shortcuts to the same command.

Note #2: To duplicate the Find dialog fix I mentioned above, simply assign the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut key to **EditFind** instead of the default **NavPaneSearch**, or you can assign a different shortcut to the former if you prefer quick access to both old and new Find dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using a macro - as you already know how to assign the key (in accepted answer), I've just provide the VBa

```
Sub NewDocumentFromTemplate()
  Documents.Add Template:=Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath) & "\Custom\Foo.dotm"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Can you add instructions how to use this with a keyboard shortcut?