# Office 2007: assign a different keyboard shortcut to "find"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, macros

I'm trying to assign a single key (F2) to the "find" command, but I cannot find it in the list of commands.

As you can see here, I can see the "find" command when it comes to add it to the Quick Access Toolbar:

[image]

---

But when it comes to assigning keyboard shortcuts, the "find" command is nowhere to be found:

[image]

---

I'm assuming that the reason it is not displaying it is because it has a built-in CTRL+F shortcut, but I want to change that.

**In short:** how can I assign F2 to the "find" command?

Comment: Office 2003 shows it as EditFind, so it's probably listed in 2007 as HomeFind. (I don't have a copy of 2007, so I'm not 100% sure about that.)

Comment: @Davidw - Thanks. That was it. It's listed as `editFind`. Go figure. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Also see last bit of my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/473330/138343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's listed by the section that it is part of in the ribbon, so it would be EditFind.

[image]